# How to configure non-path based service to path-based in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

We have a docker-based infra that uses haproxy. There are a lot of services added and is in the format:

http://example.org/serviceX

So the existing frontend and backend setup is like below which works fine:

```
frontend http_in
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    acl url_servicex path_reg ^/servicex(/.*)?$
    use_backend servicex if url_servicex

   default_backend haproxy404

backend servicex
   server servicex servicex:8082 check fall 3 rise 3 inter 1000
   
backend haproxy404
    server haproxy404 haproxy404:8081 check fall 3 rise 3 inter 1000
```

Now, I wanted to add serviceY, which has some peculiarity wherein I cannot configure it's container server for some reason to
load at something like serviceY:8083/serviceY. Otherwise, it would have been the same scenario as our existing config above.

Can anyone give hints please?

Thanks.